# How to identify which hypothesis test and what are the parameters?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

[image]

Unable to begin to determine if this is a z test, t-test and what are the parameters

Answer (score 1):

I would do tests to see if [two binomial proportions are equal](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm). I will show results from R. The link has formulas. I don't know whether you are expected to use or explain formulas. Several slightly different versions of this test are in common use. If your text covers this test, use the version there.

The method in the link and in R is to use a normal approximation to the difference of two binomial proportions; the square of a standard normal distribution is a chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom, hence the mention of chi-squared in the R output.

Test whether proportion of sales is the same: No significant difference.
(Continuity correction not used on account of large sample sizes.)

```
prop.test(c(1100, 100), c(10000,1000), cor=F)

   2-sample test for equality of proportions 
   without continuity correction

data:  c(1100, 100) out of c(10000, 1000)
X-squared = 0.93537, df = 1, p-value = 0.3335
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.009579049  0.029579049
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.11   0.10
```

Test whether proportion of warranty sales is the same: Highly significant difference.

```
prop.test(c(300, 50), c(10000,1000), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(300, 50) out of c(10000, 1000)
X-squared = 11.804, df = 1, p-value = 0.000591
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.033915744 -0.006084256
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.03   0.05
```

*Note:* Chi-squared tests or Fisher Exact tests for two-by-two tables
could also be used. But it seems you want a direct comparison of the two sample proportions in both for both car and warranty sales.